# Hints and tips to prove this inequality.

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients, integers

Let's say that $n = \lfloor{2^{\frac{k}{2}}}\rfloor$ for some integer $k \geq 3$. I need to prove this inequality:
$${n \choose k}\cdot2^{1-{k \choose 2}} < 1$$

I tried to rewrite those terms or even use induction, but with no results. Could anybody give some hints and tips on how to prove that (or some useful techniques which might come in handy in the future)?

Comment: Hint: $\binom nk \le \frac{n^k}{k!}$ always.

Comment: Certainly seems easier to prove it as $2\binom{n}{k}<2^{\binom{k}{2}}$ when $n^2\leq 2^{k}.$